# Mixed active content : http URL loaded on a https site

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

That problem is well-known and I tried the most of solutions that I have found on stackexchange.

I installed an SSL certificate on https://109.gehmert.fr/ but css and js are not loaded.

I managed to change the web/unsecure/base_url and the web/secure/base_url in command line.

I read that in the Magento configuration, I can also change the secure and unsecure base_media_url but it did not work because I do not have any js so the validation button does not work.

In database, I just have the two tables base-url and base-url-secure :

MariaDB [magento]> select * from core_config_data where path like '%web%';

Result :

- web/seo/use_rewrites
- web/unsecure/base_url
- web/secure/base_url
- web/secure/use_in_frontend
- web/secure/use_in_adminhtml

And when I am filtering on '%secure%' :

[image]

I tried this : update core_config_data set value = '{{secure_base_url}}media/' where path = 'web/secure/base_media_url';

I also tried to grep the magento folders to find the files which call unsecure resources but I did not find anything.

Best regards,

Antoine

Comment: Great, it is likely now a server issue. Are you using nginx or apache? Can you share your config..

Answer (score 0):

Open mysql database and hit the query:

```
select * from core_config_data where path like '%secure%';
```

then looking at the result, some records will use **http** and these have to be changed. Afterwards, you can change these either directly in the mysql or from the admin but this method will show you the data with their scope

this is my config and it is minimal. The simplest this config is, the simpler it will be to debug and therefore you might want to aim for this **if you do have issues with magento url and happen to have only one store in your system**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just got 4 results (path and value) : web/unsecure/base_url > http://109.gehmert.fr/, web/secure/base_url > https://109.gehmert.fr/, web/secure/use_in_frontend > 1, web/secure/use_in_adminhtml > 0. I think that I should not change the unsecure one.

Comment: You are right, it is not needed to change the unsecure ones. However, you can tackle the issue in 2 steps, initially you want to resolve the css to load and then you'd want your system to be setup correctly, right? I would change all these values should be https://109.gehmert.fr/ and clear all caches, redis included if you use it and browser cache too

Comment: I changed the 2 lines (web/secure/use_in_frontend and web/secure/use_in_adminhtml), I cleared the magento and browser caches but I still have the issue : https://109.gehmert.fr/.

Comment: Don't you think I need to add the column web/secure/base_js_url in database and to insert the value {{secure_base_url}}js/ into it ?

Comment: I updated my answer and hopefully that should hint you on what can be your next steps

Comment: I also updated my answer.

Comment: How about starting a chat tomorrow? Happy to help further

Comment: With pleasure ! I am quite a neophyte on stackexchange : we can chat here https://chat.stackexchange.com ? Or have you thought about another platform ?

Comment: ok, ready when you are, did try to head to chat room and could not see you

Comment: "user88710 has only 1 reputation, not yet enough to chat." Here is my Skype ID : imemercilesstime, I will be avalaible at 01:00 pm today.

Comment: what's your email? I will send an int on slack

Comment: contact@deoa.fr